# Using Multiple Inner Joins in SQL

Tags: sql

When running the below query I get an error saying

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
>   'diagnosis.Patient_No = 'Patient_No INNER JOIN Illness ON
>   Illness.Illness_Code = Diagnosis.Illness_Code'

```
SELECT Patient.Last_Name AS LastName,
       Patient.First_Name AS FirstName,
       Patient.Gender AS Gender,
       Patient.Age AS Age,
       Illness.Illness_Desc AS illness,
       Medication.Medication_Desc AS Medication,
       Prescription.Dosage AS Dosage
FROM Patient
INNER JOIN Diagnosis ON Patient.Patient_No = Diagnosis.Patient_No
INNER JOIN Illness ON Diagnosis.Illness_Code = Illness.Illness_Code
INNER JOIN Prescription ON Patient.Patient_No = Prescription.Patient_No
INNER JOIN Medication ON Prescription.Medication_code = Medication.Medication_code
```

I confirmed that illness_code are both in Illness and Diagnosis tables and everything should work? Not sure if during this join I need to add these illness codes to the select statement? I tried adding them to my Select and that didnt seem to work for me either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Medication.Medication_Desc AS Medication,
Prescription.Dosage AS Dosage
```

Looks like you don't have the medication and prescription tables joined in your FROM statement.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify the table for the second Patient_No column in the first join.  It should be

```
INNER JOIN Diagnosis ON Diagnosis.Patient_No = Patient.Patient_No
```

You are also selecting columns from two tables that you aren't joining on - Medication and Prescription.  However, this should give you a different error of "The multi-part identifier 'Medication.Medication_Desc' could not be bound."

The specific error you are getting sounds like the first problem I mentioned.  Here's a working SQL filter with the Medication / Prescription tables omitted.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f77a8/1)

Comment: I changed it to Patient.Patient_No and it didnt make a difference. Seriously stumped.

Comment: I updated my above code to reflect adding all of the INNER JOINS. Still not working properly. Am I using the JOIN incorrectly?

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle.  It has your exact SQL with some empty tables.  No data is returned, but it executes, so I think the problem lies elsewhere.  - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d288f/1

Answer (score 0):

Also add `INNER JOINS` for the other two tables,

```
INNER JOIN Medication ON Medication.<> = Patient.<>

INNER JOIN Prescription ON Prescription.<> = Patient.<>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't still be getting the same error.. .What is happening now?
try the below

```
 Select p.Last_Name LastName,
   p.First_Name FirstName,
   p.Gender Gender, p.Age Age,
   i.Illness_Desc illness,
   m.Medication_Desc Medication,
   s.Dosage Dosage
From Patient p
    Join Diagnosis d    On d.Patient_No = p.Patient_No
    Join Illness i      On i.Illness_Code = d.Illness_Code
    Join Prescription s On s.Patient_No = p.Patient_No
    Join Medication m   On m.Medication_code = p.Medication_code
```